# Diagonal or bent errors in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I have to make a plot where the data points have diagonal errors, i.e., the upper and lower y-error-bars have a displacement in the x-axis (see [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKo3T.png)).

I tried using axhline to create the error caps, together with plotting lines between the cap, the point, and the other cap. However this is extremely cumbersome and does not scale well.

This is the beginning of the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x    = [-0.22, 0.05, 0.25, 0.35, 0.5, 0.61,0.7,0.85,0.89,0.95]
y    = [1,2.9,5.6,7.4,9,9.6,8.7,6.3,4.5,1]
erryl  = [.8,.7,.6,.5,.4,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8]   #lower y error
erryh  = [.6,.5,.4,.3,.2,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6]   #upper y error
erryld = [.0,.0,.05,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0]  #displacement measured in the x axis
erryhd = [.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.05,.0]  #displacement measured in the x axis
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKo3T.png) is how I would like the figure to look like. Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S.: By the way, I am actually "translating" a [TGraphBentErrors](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTGraphBentErrors.html) from ROOT to matplotlib.

Comment: The non-zero values in `erryld` and `erryhd`, are they hand-placed at some indexes or can we automatically calculate their indexes? That would help with reducing the hassle.

Comment: I would need non-zero values for every index, and a different value for each...